# different ul elements overlapping in a horizontally moving div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a div that contains images that move continuously
Here is the code

```
<div class="carousel">
<ul id='country'>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=IND" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px;cursor: pointer" onclick="openind()"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=US" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=SA" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=UK" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=GRE" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=PO" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=PAK" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=ARG" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=NZ" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=AUS" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
</ul>
    <ul id='ind' style=" display: none">
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=WB" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=JH" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=UP" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=BI" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=UK" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=MH" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=MP" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=KA" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=KL" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=TN" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=AP" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
    <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60&text=AM" alt='country' style=" border-radius: 5px;height:50px"/></li>
</ul>
<div class="left-arrow carrow"></div>
<div class="right-arrow carrow"></div>
```

Here in the first ul if I click on the image IND, then these ul elements must disappear, and the next ul element must appear.The problem is that the second ul's images start appearing along with the first ul's images even before clicking the button. And when I click IND for the same happens.

Here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/adeete/bjyuA/21/

Please help.

Function to hide first ul and display second ul

```
function openind()
{
  document.getElementById('country').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('ind').style.display='block';
}
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve, but I made some update to your fiddle to effect the IND image click. http://jsfiddle.net/depaule/bjyuA/24/

Comment: What i'm trying is as the first ul is the one that is moving continuoslly.It contains a li IND ,If i click on that then the second ul should replace the first ul, i.e. the first ul should disappear and the second ul's elements should be the one moving

Comment: And still the same thing is happening.Rather it is now happening more after you updated it.I mean now all the elements of both the ul are appearing twice

Comment: *clicking the button*?? What button Ani...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are selecting all `li` from both `ul`s. You need to make the specific changes.

First add `display: block` to `country` ul

```
<ul id='country' style="display: block">
```

Next change your `ul` selector in `myAnimate` function like this

```
var $ul = $carousel.children('ul[style^="display: block"]');
```

Note: your style selector above should appear the same way you set it. Currently you have a space between `:` and `block`. So this must be persevered everywhere.

**Edit:** Updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/marudhupandiyang/bjyuA/25/

Comment: Thank you so much.I cannot upvote your answer due to lack of reputation.But thank you so much.